# EHCache on Coldfusion 9 - can I create multiple caches or disable it?

Tags: caching, coldfusion, ehcache

We have been using EHCache with CF8 for a while now with no issues.

We are now moving to CF 9 and it seems that the baked-in version of EHCache with CF 9 is actually conflicting with our EHCache setup.

So is there:

1. Any way to disable the baked-in version of EHCache? This would be a temporary solution.
2. If we use the CF9 baked-in caching, is there any way to specify more than one cache in `ehcache.xml` and most importantly, to `put` into that specific cache via the  tag?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the CacheManager using the overloaded constructor which takes the path to your ehcache config file as an argument

http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.html#CacheManager%28java.lang.String%29

This will create a non-singleton CacheManager which will play nice with CF9

Answer (score 0):

Are they using the default classpath:ehcache.xml location? If so try seeing if you can initialize your CacheManager first then their code may end up just re-using your instance.